# How can I navigate to external page post json data for print service with React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a Print service which requires parameters.
After posting parameters to the service URL, it renders a page.
I m trying to build something like the code below. I want to  post json data to an external URL and I want to see the content. How can I do it?

```
import { jsonDataModel } from "../Models/jsonDataModel";

const PrintPage = (jsonData:jsonDataModel ) => {
 
    window.location.replace('https://localhost:7205/api/print', jsonData);

    return (
        <div>PrintPage</div>
    )
}

export default PrintPage
```

i would send data as parameters like

```
window.location.replace('https://localhost:7205/api/print?parameter1=name');
```

but i'm curious, whether i can send data from body.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. Why would you try to navigate to "json any data"? That's not a URL. Please revise to use appropriate sample data and explain better.

Comment: Don't tell _me_, revise your post.

Answer (score 0):

Sending data as object to an external link can only via query string (as parameters) so you can do like :

```
'https://localhost:7205/api/print?parameter1=name1&parameter2=name2&parameter3=name3 ...etc'
```

but sending data object throw external link doesn't work , you have no access to this data outside your project like when you send it as state of Link component from react-router-dom

Comment: i already can do it. i just want to know wether i can post data to url and navigate to it. 
Because, i m planing to post a list to the url.